# Using a quadratic kernel instead of a linear kernel in the Laplace transform

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform, almost-periodic-function

Suppose $f$ is a bounded continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ such that $\int_0^\infty f(t) \exp(-xt) \: dt \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$. Does it follow that $\int_0^\infty f(t) \exp(-xt^2) \: dt \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$? Is the reverse implication true?

I suspect that the answer is "no" in both cases, so here's my real (although vague) question: is there a notion of regularity for $f$ (along the lines of the notion of almost-periodicity) such that the two limit-assertions imply each other when $f$ is regular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists  a Tauberian theorem of the following form. Suppose that $a\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$ and  for any $x>0$ the integral

$$ G(x):=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2t^2} a(t) dt $$

exists   and satisfies

$$ \sup_{x>0}|G(x)|<\infty, $$

and

$$ \lim_{x\searrow 0} G(x) = A\in\mathbb{R}. $$

The function $G(x)$ is  called the *Gauss-Weierstrass  transform* of $a$. Suppose also that the integrals

$$ L(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-xt} a(t) dt $$

exist for any $x>0$.  Then

$$ \lim_{x\searrow 0} L(x)= A= \lim_{x\searrow 0} G(x).$$

Let us point out that if $a\in L^1(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$, then   the integrals $G(x)$ and $L(x)$ exist for any $x$ and

$$ A=\int_0^\infty a(t) dt. $$

For a proof  see   Chap.I, Sec 14, Thm. 21  of the book

> **S. Bochner,  K. Chandrasekharan**:  *Fourier Transforms*, Ann. Math. Studies, vol. 19, Princeton University Press, 1949.

**Addendum** It seems that  one of Wiener's Tauberian theorem. (see J. Korevaar: *Tauberian Theory. A Century of developments*,  Theorem 5.1, Chap II).

Comment: @Liviu: Thanks, but I am confused. What is $s$? Also, does $L_{loc}^1$ mean locally integrable in the sense of being integrable over every finite interval, or is some sort of uniformity required?

Comment: That $s$ was mant to be an $x$ I fixed  the typo.  $L^1_{loc}$ means integrability on compacts, no uniformity assumed.

Comment: Looks like your addendum (about Wiener) got truncated or something (it doesn't appear to be a complete sentence). Can you re-edit it? Thanks!

Comment: @ James  I don't remember what I was attempting to say almost a year ago. Perhaps the details are in the reference I gave. I am on the road and I cannot access the book.